# Centos 7 pptpd mtu size

Tags: centos, vpn, mtu, pptpd

i'm using pptpd on centos7 as PPTP VPN Server
how can I change the MTU size on server side cause some users cannot connect to the server

thanks

Comment: Don't use PPTP at all. This protocol is deprecated and [insecure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Tunneling_Protocol#Security).

Comment: its OK, there is nothing to worried about, we just need speed and the pptp is easiest & fastest